# Hibernate cascade child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I using **Hibernate and spring data** to manage my entity with oracle DB

I have the following Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {    
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String title;
}
```

and another one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_detail")
public class UserDetail {    
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String address;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

I want when delete user the child 'user detail' also deleted (cascade)
How to solve this problem with hibernate

Comment: If you cannot change the code, you will have to do this in the database by adding a cascade on the foreign key column `user_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is to add  On Delete annotation '@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)'
above the relation Like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_detail")
public class UserDetail {    
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String address;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform cascades, you'll have to do a few changes in your code.

First of all, you'll have to map UserDetail in User entity and include a cascade setup in your relational annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {    
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserDetail detail;
}
```

PS: I'm assuming one to one relation, but feel free to map as you wish...all hibernate's relational annotations supports cascade. Mapped collections are supported as well.

By doing this, you are telling Hibernate to perform cascade whenever it performs an operation on an User entity. In case you want to tell exactly on which operations it must perform the cascade, you can do this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {    
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DELETE})
    private UserDetail detail;
}
```

You can find all CascadeTypes on Hibernate docs. Just notice that, in order to perform cascades, you should avoid using hibernate's session "update", "save" and "saveOrUpdate" methods...you should use "persist" and "merge".

Comment: thanks alot for your support, is there any alternative make me avoid change in User  entity

Comment: As far as I know, that's the only way...your entity must map the nested entities that will be affected by cascade operations.

Comment: you can find my solution below
and thanks alot for your support